# SequelizeDatabaseError - Missing Column - One to Many association

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am following along the following tutorial [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/getting-started-with-node-express-and-postgres-using-sequelize#toc-creating-todos)

Everything works up to [Listing todo-items inside todos](https://scotch.io/tutorials/getting-started-with-node-express-and-postgres-using-sequelize#listing-todo-items-inside-todos)

I have the following error report when making a get request to the server:

```
{"name":"SequelizeDatabaseError","parent":{"name":"error","length":104,"severity":"ERROR","code":"42703","position":"440","file":"parse_relation.c","line":"2743","routine":"errorMissingColumn","sql":"SELECT \"ItemSet\".\"id\", \"ItemSet\".\"title\", \"ItemSet\".\"createdAt\", \"ItemSet\".\"updatedAt\", \"items\".\"id\" AS \"items.id\", \"items\".\"content\" AS \"items.content\", \"items\".\"complete\" AS \"items.complete\", \"items\".\"createdAt\" AS \"items.createdAt\", \"items\".\"updatedAt\" AS \"items.updatedAt\", \"items\".\"itemSetId\" AS \"items.itemSetId\", \"items\".\"itemId\" AS \"items.itemId\" FROM \"ItemSets\" AS \"ItemSet\" LEFT OUTER JOIN \"Items\" AS \"items\" ON \"ItemSet\".\"id\" = \"items\".\"itemId\";"},"original":{"name":"error","length":104,"severity":"ERROR","code":"42703","position":"440","file":"parse_relation.c","line":"2743","routine":"errorMissingColumn","sql":"SELECT \"ItemSet\".\"id\", \"ItemSet\".\"title\", \"ItemSet\".\"createdAt\", \"ItemSet\".\"updatedAt\", \"items\".\"id\" AS \"items.id\", \"items\".\"content\" AS \"items.content\", \"items\".\"complete\" AS \"items.complete\", \"items\".\"createdAt\" AS \"items.createdAt\", \"items\".\"updatedAt\" AS \"items.updatedAt\", \"items\".\"itemSetId\" AS \"items.itemSetId\", \"items\".\"itemId\" AS \"items.itemId\" FROM \"ItemSets\" AS \"ItemSet\" LEFT OUTER JOIN \"Items\" AS \"items\" ON \"ItemSet\".\"id\" = \"items\".\"itemId\";"},"sql":"SELECT \"ItemSet\".\"id\", \"ItemSet\".\"title\", \"ItemSet\".\"createdAt\", \"ItemSet\".\"updatedAt\", \"items\".\"id\" AS \"items.id\", \"items\".\"content\" AS \"items.content\", \"items\".\"complete\" AS \"items.complete\", \"items\".\"createdAt\" AS \"items.createdAt\", \"items\".\"updatedAt\" AS \"items.updatedAt\", \"items\".\"itemSetId\" AS \"items.itemSetId\", \"items\".\"itemId\" AS \"items.itemId\" FROM \"ItemSets\" AS \"ItemSet\" LEFT OUTER JOIN \"Items\" AS \"items\" ON \"ItemSet\".\"id\" = \"items\".\"itemId\";"}
```

I have made small modification to the tutorial:

- I use `ItemSet`, instead of `ToDo`
- I use `Item`, instead of `ToDoItem`

ideally I'd like something to return which looks like this:
[image]

my code is available here: https://github.com/AlexanderMcNulty/seq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is `itemId` defined in the [`ItemSet`](https://github.com/AlexanderMcNulty/seq/blob/master/server/models/itemSet.js)  model.

```
ItemSet.associate = function(models) {
    ItemSet.hasMany(models.Item, {
      foreignKey: 'itemId',
      as: 'items',
    });
  };
```

I don't think you have defined `itemId` anywhere

Comment: awesome thanks, I got lost in the tutorial by missing a capitalization on one of my `itemSetId`. (i then got frustrated and invented another variable name to complicate the situation `itemId` and apparently `setid`). Thanks for the help, you even got me to read the documentation. Github repo has been updated.